# Errors in android.app.Activity.java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After setting up Android Studio, I tried to find out how few of the methods work but I can see that Activity class have got a lot of errors.

For example:

```
// Gives: cannot resolve symbol 'CallSuper'
android.annotation.CallSuper();  

// Gives: cannot resolve method 'trackActivity(android.app.Activity)'
private final Object mInstanceTracker = StrictMode.trackActivity(this); 

// Gives: cannot resolve symbol 'MainThread'
@MainThread

// **312 errors in android.app.Activity, 579 in android.view.View**
```

My application works fine though. How can i make those errors disappear and be able to see documentation of structures that cannot be resolved now?

**Details on my Android Studio 2.1.3 configuration**
Installed in Standalone SDK Manager:

- Android SDK Tools
- Android SDK Platform-tools
- Android SDK Build-tools
- SDK Platform and Sources for API 24
- SDK Platform, Documentation, Google APIs and sources for API 23
- Extras: Android Support Repository, Google Repository and Google USB Driver

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the version of Android Studio you use, errors you got?

Comment: Hey. I use 2.1.3, i have also updated the topic with what i have installed by SDK Manager. I do not see any errors in IDE Event Log or Messages or anything like this, just in sdk sources.

Comment: have you tried to Build / Clean project and rebuild afterwards?

Comment: Yes, it doesnt solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being precise, those aren't errors in the source code for `Activity/View` it's just that :

- Your IDE can't find the class `android.annotation.CallSuper` in it's  classpath.
- It cannot resolve method `trackActivity` in class `android.app.Activity`.

This is because the SDK is subset of the actual Android platform. The SDK shipped to the developers a.k.a **Public API** utilizes a lot of platform features a.k.a. **Internal APIs**, hence you can't find them in your SDK 24 classpath.

So why are all these portions hidden from developers?
It's kept hidden from developers because most of its implementation varies from device to device, plus they wouldn't be required in 99.99% cases (metaphorical figure not actual stats). You might want to have a look [here](http://www.xda-developers.com/using-internalhidden-classes-of-the-android-api/).

Comment: Attached article says step by step how to solve my problem. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

add in your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Added, i also used Sync Now, runned my app again and then checked Activity.java - nothing changed in there.

Answer (score 0):

This simply means those classes arent on the classpath. When you run an app on a mobile phone or in the emulator the platform make sure the classes are all present.

Comment: Where can i get those classes from? For example annotation classes i can find in package android.support.annotation, but Activity is using android.annotation package that does not exist anywhere. Other classes like android.util.Slog i cannot find anywhere

Comment: Why do you need those classes? They are internal packages. They dont have documentation either most of the time. If you miss something on the classpath and really wanna know where it comes from just search the android git repository for the classname/package name.

Comment: because it would be a lot faster and easier to open those classes(even without the docs) in IDE than look for them each time in google

Answer (score 0):

> ... i tried to find out how few of the methods work

The easy way to look at Android source code is to just browse it online. For example here is the [`Activity` class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java).

If you install the "Android SDK Search" plugin for Chrome, it will automatically add source links to the online Javadoc.

> How can i make those errors disappear and be able to see documentation of structures that cannot be resolved now?

The only way to view live code without compile errors is to download and build the entire [Android Open Source Project](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html).

Comment: I checked Android SDK Search in Chrome browser and it doesnt show hidden classes or methods